# Public internet website - Can it be done in SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, publishing-site, public-website

We're currently creating a new public website, but can't really figure out if we need to go with a full onpremise / azure insatallation of SharePoint server 2013, or if we can simply use SharePoint online.

I found a comparison of the two here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx?redir=0

This states that a lot of features are not availible in SharePoint online, like variations and publishing templates. However I also found this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/about-publishing-enabled-site-templates-HA102802341.aspx that indicates publishing template is availible. So I'm a bit confused.

These are the features I need:

- Variations
- Custom ContentTypes
- Managed metadata navigation
- friendly urls

Am I able to build the site using SharePoint online?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live without variations, or make use of the Content Search Web Part, I'd go for SharePoint Online. CSWP does (by description) almost the same thing, but uses a different source: Search Index.

- [Variations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx)

> Variations, translations. Syncs content from a source location to other locations by audience (SharePoint Server Only)

- [Custom ContentTypes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx)

> Content types, columns, fields. Reusable collections of metadata for categories of items or documents. (SharePoint Server only)

Unless you make use of Cross Site Publishing and Content Search Web part:

> Use cross-site collection publishing to publish content, use content types and site columns to structure content, provide secure access to parts of the site, offer English and Spanish views. (SharePoint Online)

- [Managed metadata navigation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx)

> Term-based navigation. Website navigation is based on SharePoint term sets

- [Friendly urls](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx)

> Friendly URLs are now applied to the web pages on the Public Website. For example, the Contact Us page might look like www.website.com/contact-us/